# Can't get joomla update notification even after perge cache action

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, joomla3.0

i wasn't getting any updates notifications of joomla update as my current version is 2.5.x and i want to update to 3.x at least. But after doing purge cache action as according to [this solution](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/4468/no-notification-to-update-to-latest-joomla-version) states.

But after this i get to see this (How can this say the lower version to new version?)

[image]

Is there any other way i can get to notify to update to joomla version 3.x ?

Comment: For non-development Joomla questions, please use http://joomla.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to options of the Joomla update manager and switch from Long Term Support to Short Term Support.

Answer (score 1):

This way you can update Joomla 2.5.x only to Joomla 2.5.28 (which is the last release of 2.5 series). If you want to have Joomla 3, then you must do a migration, like that: https://docs.joomla.org/Joomla_2.5_to_3.x_Step_by_Step_Migration

Answer (score 1):

If you want to upgrade your Joomla to latest version then Just Go to Extension manager and install the following stable package.
[Download Joomla Update package](http://joomlacode.org/gf/download/frsrelease/20087/162545/Joomla_3.4.3-Stable-Update_Package.zip)